# jQuery "Exception thrown and not caught" issue with IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "pages.php",
  data: "hash="+s,
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(msg){
     $('#main').append(msg);
}
```

Works fine in FF, Chrome, Opera, and Safari.

In IE9, it displays an error in the console like:

> SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught
>   jquery.min,js line 123 character 138

Please help me with this.

Comment: You're missing `});`, but I assume that's just a copy/paste mistake. Try using a non-minified jQuery; you should get a better handle on what's going wrong based on the exception line number.

Comment: I'd love to see a demo of that behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this error in IE7. Upgrading to the latest version of jQuery (1.6.1) made it go away.

Comment: funny enough, i had this issue with 1.6.1 and needed to upgrade to 1.6.4 to get rid of this error...

Answer (score 0):

I was have the same error SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught jquery.min,js line 85 character 132" .  You'll notice mine was at line 85 though using jquery 1.4.4.  I was adding a class in IE7 that included the css "filter" property, and I was using it for a background gradient.  If I removed either the jQuery that added the class out of my script.js or the filter property out of my CSS file it fixed the error.  Don't know exactly why, but there was definitely a correlation in my situation.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer